# Add an icon for the CMFCPropertyGridProperty class

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, icons

In my app I use `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` and `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` classes for creating the properties. I would like to add icons for some my properties using the `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` class, as  I shown on this image:

[image]

Is it possible? Please any ideas  for solving my question.